# Retornar 2 objetos en un metodo

Tags: java

Este es un programita basico que determina quien tiene la mayor de edad.

Mi pregunta es, como hago para devolver 2 objetos en el return del metodo mayor cuando se cumple la condicion?
Se que creando un objeto ahi mismo en el metodo mayor y pasandole los parametros es una opcion porque ya lo probé y cumple con lo que se le pide, pero pienso que la manera mas correcta es enviarle los 2 objetos, es lo que veo mas logico.

```
public class PersonaPub {
    //Atributos
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    String  nombre2;
    int edad2;
    
    //Constructores
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad, String nombre2, int edad2) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre2 = nombre2;
        this.edad2 = edad2;
    }
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    
}
    
    //Metodos
    public void imprimir() {
        // Aqui verifico si las personas tienen la misma edad
        if (this.nombre2 == null)
            System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es : " + this.nombre);
        else
            System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es : " + this.nombre + " " + this.nombre2);
        }
    
    //Determina el que tenga la mayor edad
    public PersonaPub mayor(PersonaPub per1) {
        
        if (this.edad < per1.edad)
            return per1;
        if (this.edad > per1.edad)
            return this;
        else
            return (per1,this); //NECESITO RETORNAR AQUI 2 OBJETOS PERO DE ESTA MANERA ME DA ERROR.
        }
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PersonaPub persona1 = new PersonaPub("Antonio", 50);
        PersonaPub persona2 = new PersonaPub("Adriana", 50);
        PersonaPub personaMayor = persona1.mayor(persona2);
        personaMayor.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo estás viendo mal. Si quieres saber quién es mayor el método  debería devolver 1 si p2 es mayor que p1. - 1 si p2 es menor que p1. Y 0 si ambos son iguales. Ya con ese valor se evalúa que se debe hacer.

Comment: Si, teoricamente tienes toda la razon. Mas en este caso pues ya con fines de aprendizaje queria saber como devolver 2 objetos en un return. Muchas gracias @Lobos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas retornar 2 objetos podrías realizarlo modificando tu método para que este retorne una lista de objetos `PersonaPub`:

```
   public List<PersonaPub> mayor(PersonaPub per1, PersonaPub per2) {
        List<PersonaPub> personasMayores = new ArrayList<PersonaPub>();
        if (per1.edad < per2.edad){
            personasMayores.add(per2);
        }else if (per1.edad > per2.edad){
            personasMayores.add(per1);
        }else{
            personasMayores.add(per1);
            personasMayores.add(per2);
        }            
        return personasMayores;
    }
```

Esta lista que retorna puede ser usada para imprimir la o las personas con mayor edad:

```
public class PersonaPub {
    //Atributos
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    String  nombre2;
    int edad2;
    
        //Constructores
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad, String nombre2, int edad2) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre2 = nombre2;
        this.edad2 = edad2;
    }
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    
}
    
     //Metodos
    public static void imprimir(List<PersonaPub> personasMayores) {
        // Hay más de 1 persona con la misma edad mayor
        if (personasMayores.size()>1){
         for(PersonaPub persona : personasMayores)   {
            System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es : " + persona.nombre); 
         }             
        } else {
            System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es : " + personasMayores.get(0).nombre);
        }
    }
   
     public List<PersonaPub> mayor(PersonaPub per1, PersonaPub per2) {
        List<PersonaPub> personasMayores = new ArrayList<PersonaPub>();
        if (per1.edad < per2.edad){
            personasMayores.add(per2);
        }else if (per1.edad > per2.edad){
            personasMayores.add(per1);
        }else{
            personasMayores.add(per1);
            personasMayores.add(per2);
        }            
        return personasMayores;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonaPub persona1 = new PersonaPub("Antonio", 50);
        PersonaPub persona2 = new PersonaPub("Adriana", 50);
        List<PersonaPub> personaMayor = persona1.mayor(persona1, persona2);
        imprimir(personaMayor);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Gracias! a pesar de que me plantearon soluciones mas basicas, como mandar un System.out.println("Las dos personas tienen la misma edad"), en este caso me interesaba era aprender como mandar 2 o mas objetos como respuesta. Agradecido! excelente.

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitas no puedes hacerlo como tal (un doble retorno, en todo caso, puedes usar una lista). Pero realmente no tienes la necesidad de devolver las dos personas solo para llamar a otro método que te diga cuál es mayor, cuando puedes hacerlo en uno solo...

```
public class PersonaPub {
        //Atributos
        String nombre;
        int edad;
        String  nombre2;
        int edad2;

        //Constructores
        public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad, String nombre2, int edad2) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.nombre2 = nombre2;
            this.edad2 = edad2;
        }
        public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;

        }

        //Metodos

        //Determina el que tenga la mayor edad
        public void mayor(PersonaPub per1) {

            if (this.edad < per1.edad)
                System.out.println(per1.nombre + " es mayor");
            else if (this.edad > per1.edad)
                System.out.println(this.nombre + " es mayor");
            else
                System.out.println("Las dos personas tienen la misma edad"); //NECESITO RETORNAR AQUI 2 OBJETOS PERO DE ESTA MANERA ME DA ERROR.
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
            PersonaPub persona1 = new PersonaPub("Antonio", 50);
            PersonaPub persona2 = new PersonaPub("Adriana", 50);
            persona1.mayor(persona2);
        }
    }
```

Otra opción, si quieres conservar tu código, podría ser:

```
public class PersonaPub {
    //Atributos
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    String  nombre2;
    int edad2;

    //Constructores
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad, String nombre2, int edad2) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre2 = nombre2;
        this.edad2 = edad2;
    }
    public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;

    }

    //Metodos
    public void imprimir() {
            System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es : " + this.nombre + " " + this.nombre2);
    }

    //Determina el que tenga la mayor edad
    public PersonaPub mayor(PersonaPub per1) {

        if (this.edad < per1.edad)
            return per1;
        if (this.edad > per1.edad)
            return this;
        else
            return (null); //NECESITO RETORNAR AQUI 2 OBJETOS PERO DE ESTA MANERA ME DA ERROR.
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PersonaPub persona1 = new PersonaPub("Antonio", 49);
        PersonaPub persona2 = new PersonaPub("Adriana", 50);
        PersonaPub personaMayor = persona1.mayor(persona2);
        if (personaMayor==null)  System.out.println("Ambas personas tienen la misma edad");

        else personaMayor.imprimir();
    }
    }
```

Pero en mi opinión, si solo necesitas saber e imprimir quién es mayor, la primera opción sería mejor, ya que ahorras código innecesario...

pd: No entiendo del todo lo de nombre2 y edad2, los dejé porque supongo que puede que los uses luego en alguna otra parte? Si es sólo porque estuviste buscando otras vias para devolver las dos personas, haciendo uso del segundo constructor que tienes por ahí, el programa quedaría aún más limpio:

```
public class PersonaPub {
        //Atributos
        String nombre;
        int edad;

        //Constructor
        public PersonaPub(String nombre, int edad) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;

        }

        //Metodos
        //Determina el que tenga la mayor edad
        public void mayor(PersonaPub per1) {
            if (this.edad < per1.edad)
                System.out.println(per1.nombre + " es mayor");
            else if (this.edad > per1.edad)
                System.out.println(this.nombre + " es mayor");
            else
                System.out.println("Las dos personas tienen la misma edad");
        }
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            PersonaPub persona1 = new PersonaPub("Antonio", 49);
            PersonaPub persona2 = new PersonaPub("Adriana", 50);
            persona1.mayor(persona2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si, exactamente el nombre2 y edad2 fue buscando otras vias. A pesar de que me interesaba era la manera de devolver 2 objetos en un return, las soluciones que me planteastes me sirvieron de mucho para ver la solucion de manera mas pracica. Muchisimas gracias @Rodrigo.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido al menos. No te planteé la devolución de una lista porque lo tenías ya en otra respuesta y, al igual que nombre2 y edad 2, pensaba que era más un intento de solución a "Cómo saber qué persona es mayor mediante un método". Solo recordarte que hay más de un tipo de dato con el que puedes devolver un conjunto. A parte de un array de toda la vida ( PersonasPub[] ) tienes esto: http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/lja-2012-13/sesion02-apuntes.html . Un saludo!

Comment: Excelente, ya le voy a echar un ojo a eso. Muy agradecido de antemano.